# how to create a map in avro json schema

Tags: avro

Hi so im trying to create a map Map<String, int>, following an example i saw i set up my json

```
{
  "name": "MapRecord",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "map",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": "int"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but the error i keep getting is the following:

```
"record" is not a defined name. The type of the "MapRecord" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.
```

i have also tried this example from the spec.

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "type": "map",
  "values": "long",
  "default": {}
}
```

"map" is not a defined name. when compiling im using 1.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it..

```
{"name": "example", "type": {"type": "map", "values": "string"}}
```